# Why can I change the drive with C: but not with HKCU:?

Tags: powershell, filesystems

In a PowerShell session, I can change a file system drive with `C:`, `D:` etc:

```
PS: C:\> d:
PS: D:\> c:
PS: C:\>
```

However, trying the same thing with a registry drive (`HKCU:`) does not work:

```
PS: C:\> hkcu:
hkcu: : The term 'hkcu:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. ....
```

However, I *can* change drive using `set-location` (`cd`):

```
PS: C:\> cd hkcu:
PS: HKCU:\>
```

I am surprised about this behavor which I feel is inconsistent and would like to know why this is or what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem drive names (`C:`, `D:`, etc.) are explicitly defined as functions; the registry "drives" (`HKCU:` etc.) are not. You can enable the same behavior for the registry "drives" by defining functions for them in the same way:

```
function HKCU: {
    Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
}
```